# Npm Install DevDependencies in separate directory

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way for npm install to install the devDevpendencies in a separate directory enabling the ability to run build tasks while excluding the devDependencies in a dynamic/simple way?

Comment: If you use grunt, you could `require` your package.json in your Gruntfile.js and then move all the folders under `devDependencies` via a custom task.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this question. I ended up using `npm prune --production` before my task, it will remove the packages specified in your devDependencies from the node_modules folder.

[npm prune docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible, https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html states that the modules have to be in `node_modules`.

For your purposes you could copy everything but the `node_modules` folder and do `npm install --production` in the new copied folder, so you will only have production dependencies in the build.

This should accomplish what you want without much work:

```
rsync -av --progress yourproject yourbuilddir --exclude node_modules
cd yourbuilddir && npm install --production
```